# How to make generated plot be text-selectable in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I came across the paper in here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.00020.pdf, which has very nice-formatted plot with selectable text in almost every figure and table.

[image]

I was wondering how to generate those text-selectable figures in python ?

Comment: Maybe it works if you save your image in eps format? Or svg? It probably also depends on how the pdf is generated.

Comment: Just checked, could produce it with `.eps` and then use `graphicx` + `epstopdf` package in latex. Not sure if it is presented as well as the ones in the paper, but at least now text is selectable.